# Nokia Lumia 720-Lock Screen does not stretch all the way down

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

Nokia lumia 720.

I recently installed the weather app to display on my lock screen, and thats when the issue began to show.

Earlier, the lock screen would allow me to drag it down (while still being locked) and show notifications for the apps- email, whatsapp etc.

Now, the lockscreen does not drag all the way down. It stops mid way. I uninstalled the weather app, and even then, the problem continues.

Help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: So you can't drag down the notification center past half of the screen?

Comment: Restart your mobile once and see. And if it doesn't work then try soft reset..